# Wrong error in SSIS - [Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the ResultSetType: “ResultSetType_Rowset”

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an Execute SQL task which gives returns only one row with one column - a number. I set my result set to single row. Despite that, the task fails. Why ? How do I fix it ?

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: There is an invalid number of result bindings returned for the 
ResultSetType: "ResultSetType_Rowset".
```

Comment: Did the SQL you executed return no result sets at all? Are the result sets bound on the Result Sets page?

Comment: @JonSeigel - It returned a number inside SQL server. I don't understand the meaning of the second question.

Comment: Edit the Execute SQL task; on the left side in the list, select Result Set. Did you map the result set to a variable on that page?

Comment: And if you've mapped the output to a variable, what is the data type of the variable you've mapped to?

Comment: @JonSeigel - yes, i did that and it works never figured out other things.

Comment: Soooo, is this still an issue?

Comment: No, but I never figured out some things. I changed my code to make it work. I will add what I did not understand.

Comment: added new info just now. I need to figure out the reason for things.

Comment: The format on Stack Exchange makes it difficult to continue a "string" of problems in the same question. I'm going to roll back the post to the original version. If you're having a separate problem, please put that in a new question. Thanks.

Comment: @JonSeigel - thank you very much jon. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Execute SQL Task, when the Result Set property is set to any value except None, the result set(s) must be mapped on the Result Set page, as shown below.

The "Result Name" column is a bit misleading; what's actually required is a zero-based *number*.

[image]

Unfortunately, none of these requirements are validated at design-time, so the editor will happily let you click OK without entering all the necessary information.